# email sending with a slider fails

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-email, codeigniter-3

i am trying to send an email with slider ... now every style effects in email except sliding the slide part..

here is my model function  area..

```
        $message='<html>
<head>
<style>
.ReadMsgBody { width: 100%; background-color: #F6F6F6; }
.ExternalClass { width: 100%; background-color: #F6F6F6; }
body { width: 100%; background-color: #f6f6f6; margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; font-family: Georgia,  serif }
table { border-collapse: collapse !important; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; }

@-ms-viewport{ width: device-width; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 639px){
.wrapper{ width:100%;  padding: 0 !important; }
}    

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){ 
.centerClass{ margin:0 auto !important; }         
.imgClass{ width:100% !important; height:auto; }    
.wrapper{ width:320px; padding: 0 !important; }  
.header{ width:320px; padding: 0 !important; background-image: url(http://placehold.it/320x400) !important; }   
.container{ width:300px;  padding: 0 !important; }
.mobile{ width:300px; display:block; padding: 0 !important; text-align:center !important;}
.mobile50{ width:300px; padding: 0 !important; text-align:center; }
*[class="mobileOff"] { width: 0px !important; display: none !important; }
*[class*="mobileOn"] { display: block !important; max-height:none !important; }
}




/* Slider */

.sliderFallback:hover {opacity:0.85;filter:alpha(opacity=85);}

a#rotator img {
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
-ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
}

a#rotator img:hover { 
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(360deg); 
-o-transform: rotate(360deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(360deg); 
}

.sliderFallback { -webkit-animation: disapear 10s infinite; -moz-animation: disapear 10s infinite; -o-animation: disapear 10s infinite; animation: disapear 10s infinite; }

@-webkit-keyframes disapear {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
    }

@-moz-keyframes disapear {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes disapear {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
    }
@keyframes disapear {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
    }

#slider_theme.activeSlider{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 100px;
    height: auto;
}

#slider_theme.activeSlider .control{
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    animation: slider-navigate 10s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: slider-navigate 10s infinite;
    -moz-animation: slider-navigate 10s infinite;
    -o-animation: slider-navigate 10s infinite;
    animation: slider-navigate 10s infinite;
    font-size: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

#slider_theme .control img{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


#slider_theme .control img:first-child{
    width: 100%;
}

#slider_theme.activeSlider .control img{
    -moz-animation: show-width 10s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: show-width 10s infinite;
    -o-animation: show-width 10s infinite;
    animation: show-width 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes show-width {
    0%{ width: 25%; max-width: 25%; }
    100%{ width: 25%; max-width: 25%; }
}

@-moz-keyframes show-width {
    0%{ width: 25%; max-width: 25%; }
    100%{ width: 25%; max-width: 25%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes show-width {
    0%{ width: 25%; max-width: 25%; }
    100%{ width: 25%; max-width: 25%; }
}

@-o-keyframes show-width {
    0%{ width: 25%; max-width: 25%; }
    100%{ width: 25%; max-width: 25%; }
}

@keyframes slider-navigate {
    0%{ left: 0%; display: block; width: 400%; }
    12%{ left: 0%; }
    34%{ left: -100%; }
    46%{ left: -100%; }
    68%{ left: -200%; }
    80%{ left: -200%; }
    100%{ left: 0%;  width: 400%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slider-navigate {
    0%{ left: 0%; display: block; width: 400%; }
    12%{ left: 0%; }
    34%{ left: -100%; }
    46%{ left: -100%; }
    68%{ left: -200%; }
    80%{ left: -200%; }
    100%{ left: 0%;  width: 400%; }
}

@-moz-keyframes slider-navigate {
    0%{ left: 0%; display: block; width: 400%; }
    12%{ left: 0%; }
    34%{ left: -100%; }
    46%{ left: -100%; }
    68%{ left: -200%; }
    80%{ left: -200%; }
    100%{ left: 0%;  width: 400%; }
}

@-o-keyframes slider-navigate {
    0%{ left: 0%; display: block; width: 400%; }
    12%{ left: 0%; }
    34%{ left: -100%; }
    46%{ left: -100%; }
    68%{ left: -200%; }
    80%{ left: -200%; }
    100%{ left: 0%;  width: 400%; }
}

body[yahoo] #slider_theme .control img{
    display: none;
}

body[yahoo] #slider_theme .control img:first-child{
    display: block !important;
}    
</style>

    <title>Slider</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <!--[if gte mso 15]>
    <style type="text/css">
        table { font-size:1px; line-height:0; mso-margin-top-alt:1px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly; }
        * { mso-line-height-rule: exactly; }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->    

</head>
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" style="background-color:#F6F6F6;  font-family:Georgia,serif; margin:0; padding:0; min-width: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust:none;">

    <!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
    <img style="min-width:640px; display:block; margin:0; padding:0" class="mobileOff" width="640" height="1" src="https://s14.postimg.org/7139vfhzx/spacer.gif">
    <!--<![endif]-->

    <!-- Start Background -->
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#F6F6F6">
        <tr>
            <td width="100%" valign="top" align="center">


                <!-- Start Wrapper  -->
                <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#222222">
                    <tr>
                        <td height="20" style="font-size:10px; line-height:10px;">   </td><!-- Spacer -->
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">

                            <!-- Start Container  -->
                            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="600" class="mobile" style="font-family:Georgia; font-size:12px; line-height:20px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase; letter-spacing:2px; color:#FFFFFF;" align="center">
                                        Slider
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- Start Container  -->                   

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="20" style="font-size:10px; line-height:10px;"> </td><!-- Spacer -->
                    </tr>                        
                </table> 
                <!-- End Wrapper  -->                


                <!-- Start Wrapper  -->
                <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <tr>
                        <td height="20" style="font-size:10px; line-height:10px;">   </td><!-- Spacer -->
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">

                            <!-- Start Container  -->
                            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="600" class="mobile" style="font-family:arial; font-size:12px; line-height:18px;">

                                        <div id="slider_theme" class="activeSlider">
                                            <div class="control">
                                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/600x400/779ECB" class="sliderupdate1" style="width: 100%;" />
                                            <!--[if !mso]><!-->
                                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/600x400/77DD77" class="sliderupdate2" style="max-width: 0.1px; width: 0.1px;" />
                                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/600x400/FFB347" class="sliderupdate3" style="max-width: 0.1px; width: 0.1px;" />
                                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/600x400/336699" class="sliderupdate4" style="max-width: 0.1px; width: 0.1px;" /> <!-- FallBack -->
                                            <!--<![endif]-->
                                            </div>

                                            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="clear: both;"></div>                                        

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- Start Container  -->                   

                        </td>
                    </tr>                       
                </table> 
                <!-- End Wrapper  --> 



                <!-- Start Wrapper  -->
                <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <tr>
                        <td height="50" style="font-size:10px; line-height:10px;">   </td><!-- Spacer -->
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">

                            <!-- Start Container  -->
                            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="600" class="mobile" style="font-family:Georgia; font-size:12px; line-height:18px;" align="center">

                                        <!-- Start Content -->
                                        <table width="500" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="500" class="mobile" style="font-family:Georgia; font-size:26px; line-height:32px;" align="center">
                                                    Slider for email.
                                                </td>               
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td height="30" style="font-size:10px; line-height:10px;"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="500" class="mobile" style="font-family:Georgia; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; color:#747474;" align="center">
                                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sit amet tincidunt ligula, at rutrum dolor. Nunc laoreet interdum neque, sit amet ornare leo imperdiet nec. Suspendisse gravida eget lectus vel sollicitudin. Nunc vulputate a ante in sagittis. 
                                                </td>               
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        <!-- End Content -->                                        

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- Start Container  -->                   

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="60" style="font-size:10px; line-height:10px;"> </td><!-- Spacer -->
                    </tr>                        
                </table> 
                <!-- End Wrapper  -->



                <!-- Start Wrapper  -->
                <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#222222">
                    <tr>
                        <td height="20" style="font-size:10px; line-height:10px;">   </td><!-- Spacer -->
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">

                            <!-- Start Container  -->
                            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="600" class="mobile" style="font-family:Georgia; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#FFFFFF;" align="center">
                                        &copy; 2015 Slider
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- Start Container  -->                   

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="20" style="font-size:10px; line-height:10px;"> </td><!-- Spacer -->
                    </tr>                        
                </table> 
                <!-- End Wrapper  -->                  


            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- End Background -->

</body>
</html>'

                ;
        $message .= $postdata['message']."<br/><br/>";
```

please help me to fix this issue....now every style effects in email except sliding ..

Comment: Please edit your question to include only the shortest code possible to reproduce the same errors. People don't like to look at a whole chunk of code...

Comment: now i edit my qustn ...can u help me

Comment: I've seen this carousel before and it's slightly buggy. There are 4 slides, but it won't ever show the 4th one and needs a lot of tweaking to the css

Answer (score 0):

I made the 4th slide show with the animation you were working on. Wasn't that hard once you know where to make the change to.

Your slider_theme was set to 100%, i change it to 600px and overflow took care of the hidden bit. Your images are increasing in size with this set to 35%:

```
@keyframes show-width {
    0%{ width: 100%; max-width: 100%; }
    100%{ width: 100%; max-width: 100%; }
}
```

then keyframe was increasing the size to 400%

```
@keyframes slider-navigate
```

If the size increase was intended then you can put it back in.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.ReadMsgBody { width: 100%; background-color: #F6F6F6; }
.ExternalClass { width: 100%; background-color: #F6F6F6; }
body { width: 100%; background-color: #f6f6f6; margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; font-family: Georgia,  serif }
table { border-collapse: collapse !important; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; }

@-ms-viewport{ width: device-width; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 639px){
.wrapper{ width:100%;  padding: 0 !important; }
}    

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){ 
.centerClass{ margin:0 auto !important; }         
.imgClass{ width:100% !important; height:auto; }    
.wrapper{ width:320px; padding: 0 !important; }  
.header{ width:320px; padding: 0 !important; background-image: url(http://placehold.it/320x400) !important; }   
.container{ width:300px;  padding: 0 !important; }
.mobile{ width:300px; display:block; padding: 0 !important; text-align:center !important;}
.mobile50{ width:300px; padding: 0 !important; text-align:center; }
*[class="mobileOff"] { width: 0px !important; display: none !important; }
*[class*="mobileOn"] { display: block !important; max-height:none !important; }
}




/* Slider */

.sliderFallback:hover {opacity:0.85;filter:alpha(opacity=85);}

a#rotator img {
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
-ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
}

a#rotator img:hover { 
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(360deg); 
-o-transform: rotate(360deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(360deg); 
}

.sliderFallback { -webkit-animation: disapear 10s infinite; -moz-animation: disapear 10s infinite; -o-animation: disapear 10s infinite; animation: disapear 10s infinite; }

@-webkit-keyframes disapear {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
    }

@-moz-keyframes disapear {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes disapear {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
    }
@keyframes disapear {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
    }

#slider_theme.activeSlider{
    position: relative;
    /*width: 100%;*/
 width:600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 100px;
    height: auto;
}

#slider_theme.activeSlider .control{
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    animation: slider-navigate 10s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: slider-navigate 10s infinite;
    -moz-animation: slider-navigate 10s infinite;
    -o-animation: slider-navigate 10s infinite;
    animation: slider-navigate 10s infinite;
    font-size: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

#slider_theme .control img{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


#slider_theme .control img:first-child{
    width: 100%;
}

#slider_theme.activeSlider .control img{
    -moz-animation: show-width 10s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: show-width 10s infinite;
    -o-animation: show-width 10s infinite;
    animation: show-width 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes show-width {
    0%{ width: 100%; max-width: 100%; }
    100%{ width: 100%; max-width: 100%; }
}

@-moz-keyframes show-width {
    0%{ width: 100%; max-width: 100%; }
    100%{ width: 100%; max-width: 100%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes show-width {
    0%{ width: 100%; max-width: 100%; }
    100%{ width: 100%; max-width: 100%; }
}

@-o-keyframes show-width {
    0%{ width: 100%; max-width: 100%; }
    100%{ width: 100%; max-width: 100%; }
}

@keyframes slider-navigate {
    0%{ left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; }
    25%{ left: -100%; }
    50%{ left: -200%; }
    75%{ left: -300%; }
 100%{ left: -400%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slider-navigate {
    0%{ left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; }
    25%{ left: -100%; }
    50%{ left: -200%; }
    75%{ left: -300%; }
 100%{ left: -400%; }
}

@-moz-keyframes slider-navigate {
    0%{ left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; }
    25%{ left: -100%; }
    50%{ left: -200%; }
    75%{ left: -300%; }
 100%{ left: -400%; }
}

@-o-keyframes slider-navigate {
    0%{ left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; }
    25%{ left: -100%; }
    50%{ left: -200%; }
    75%{ left: -300%; }
 100%{ left: -400%; }
}

body[yahoo] #slider_theme .control img{
    display: none;
}

body[yahoo] #slider_theme .control img:first-child{
    display: block !important;
}    
</style>

    <title>Slider</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <!--[if gte mso 15]>
    <style type="text/css">
        table { font-size:1px; line-height:0; mso-margin-top-alt:1px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly; }
        * { mso-line-height-rule: exactly; }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->    

</head>
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" style="background-color:#F6F6F6;  font-family:Georgia,serif; margin:0; padding:0; min-width: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust:none;">

    <!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
    <img style="min-width:640px; display:block; margin:0; padding:0" class="mobileOff" width="640" height="1" src="https://s14.postimg.org/7139vfhzx/spacer.gif">
    <!--<![endif]-->

    <!-- Start Background -->
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#F6F6F6">
        <tr>
            <td width="100%" valign="top" align="center">


                <!-- Start Wrapper  -->
                <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#222222">
                    <tr>
                        <td height="20" style="font-size:10px; line-height:10px;">   </td><!-- Spacer -->
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">

                            <!-- Start Container  -->
                            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="600" class="mobile" style="font-family:Georgia; font-size:12px; line-height:20px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase; letter-spacing:2px; color:#FFFFFF;" align="center">
                                        Slider
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- Start Container  -->                   

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="20" style="font-size:10px; line-height:10px;"> </td><!-- Spacer -->
                    </tr>                        
                </table> 
                <!-- End Wrapper  -->                


                <!-- Start Wrapper  -->
                <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <tr>
                        <td height="20" style="font-size:10px; line-height:10px;">   </td><!-- Spacer -->
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">

                            <!-- Start Container  -->
                            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="600" class="mobile" style="font-family:arial; font-size:12px; line-height:18px;">

                                        <div id="slider_theme" class="activeSlider">
                                            <div class="control">

<img src="http://www.placehold.it/600x400/779ECB" class="sliderupdate1" /><!--[if !mso]><!-->
<img src="http://www.placehold.it/600x400/77DD77" class="sliderupdate2" />
<img src="http://www.placehold.it/600x400/FFB347" class="sliderupdate3" />
<img src="http://www.placehold.it/600x400/336699" class="sliderupdate4" /> <!-- FallBack -->
<!--<![endif]-->
                                            </div>

                                            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="clear: both;"></div>                                        

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- Start Container  -->                   

                        </td>
                    </tr>                       
                </table> 
                <!-- End Wrapper  --> 



                <!-- Start Wrapper  -->
                <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <tr>
                        <td height="50" style="font-size:10px; line-height:10px;">   </td><!-- Spacer -->
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">

                            <!-- Start Container  -->
                            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="600" class="mobile" style="font-family:Georgia; font-size:12px; line-height:18px;" align="center">

                                        <!-- Start Content -->
                                        <table width="500" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="500" class="mobile" style="font-family:Georgia; font-size:26px; line-height:32px;" align="center">
                                                    Slider for email.
                                                </td>               
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td height="30" style="font-size:10px; line-height:10px;"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="500" class="mobile" style="font-family:Georgia; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; color:#747474;" align="center">
                                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sit amet tincidunt ligula, at rutrum dolor. Nunc laoreet interdum neque, sit amet ornare leo imperdiet nec. Suspendisse gravida eget lectus vel sollicitudin. Nunc vulputate a ante in sagittis. 
                                                </td>               
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        <!-- End Content -->                                        

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- Start Container  -->                   

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="60" style="font-size:10px; line-height:10px;"> </td><!-- Spacer -->
                    </tr>                        
                </table> 
                <!-- End Wrapper  -->



                <!-- Start Wrapper  -->
                <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#222222">
                    <tr>
                        <td height="20" style="font-size:10px; line-height:10px;">   </td><!-- Spacer -->
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">

                            <!-- Start Container  -->
                            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="600" class="mobile" style="font-family:Georgia; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#FFFFFF;" align="center">
                                        &copy; 2015 Slider
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- Start Container  -->                   

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="20" style="font-size:10px; line-height:10px;"> </td><!-- Spacer -->
                    </tr>                        
                </table> 
                <!-- End Wrapper  -->                  


            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- End Background -->

</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if this is what you were after.